# How to get the register device name from OKTA API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, okta, okta-api

I have a requirement to display the OKTA register device name on the screen like the OKTA does for you.

[image]

In the picture above it display **(Pixel 2 XL)** where is the OKTA API to get the register device name

I am referring to OKTA dev API but didn't found anywhere

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/

Any idea where can I find ???

Comment: I'd try asking on the Okta forums? There's a link on the documentation page under 'support'. But I'd guess if it's not in the API responses you're getting then you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the userid you can call [the factors list API](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#list-enrolled-factors) to get the enrolled MFA factors for the user.

Which will get you back a body like:

```
[
{
    "id": "opffxq5v54xO5kdsa0x6",
    "factorType": "push",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "vendorName": "OKTA",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "created": "2020-05-07T20:49:49.000Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-20T13:33:58.000Z",
    "profile": {
        "credentialId": "test@test.com",
        "deviceType": "SmartPhone_Android",
        "keys": [
            {
                "kty": "RSA",
                "use": "sig",
                "kid": "default",
                "e": "AQAB",
                "n": "j_rlzlG07lZy_TegQPjllleeaGxxDsrtFNaoQHhDowV1z54okXdDobyJo5B9rcCkP7-i0EniNdaCFDj8xugG7WSmcDRzr46AujT7nFVPI5Z7EZE9IaLdYLP0Hg0nRaC3qhHPdv8JGszle8t0Fej1eR-AqT1mrsNUM3-k44_Axj47xhAkIPoxCjyvvA8W1FWKQbECe_y-HtlcLksJlW03WDt_bCdKwx2uVqca1yiEIF3HwhHtpK1dfwosjyEvfpTtsUWtKJVsJiksLajDhu9dGN3JcOT9unsLbWcyWc-kfQ9_oiaMikZCvtbONGSgVjtBttc95-8CHMw-tpA4HCRlcw"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Pixel 4 XL",
        "platform": "ANDROID",
        "version": "29"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6/factors/opffxq5v54xO5kdsa0x6",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "GET",
                    "DELETE"
                ]
            }
        },
        "verify": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6/factors/opffxq5v54xO5kdsa0x6/verify",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "POST"
                ]
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "ostgppjgvFiLfBv850x6",
    "factorType": "token:software:totp",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "vendorName": "OKTA",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "created": "2020-05-20T13:33:58.000Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-20T13:33:58.000Z",
    "profile": {
        "credentialId": "test@test.com"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6/factors/ostgppjgvFiLfBv850x6",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "GET",
                    "DELETE"
                ]
            }
        },
        "verify": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6/factors/ostgppjgvFiLfBv850x6/verify",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "POST"
                ]
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "https://<yourtenant>.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/00u9ivp5ft7EHNTRW0x6",
            "hints": {
                "allow": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

The device information is shown under the factorProfile (profile.name) which is documented [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#list-enrolled-factors) but doesn't show an example of push.